# Spark SQL analog for Redshift (Oracle) "SYSDATE" or "CURRENT_DATE"

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

Is there any date function which is supported in Spark SQL for getting current date?

Comment: Have you tried searching for an answer already? What else have you tried? Unless Spark SQL is implemented very differently than SQL specifications, you should just be able to `SELECT NOW();` to get the current timestamp.

Comment: `current_date` seems to work:  https://databricks.com/blog/2015/09/16/spark-1-5-dataframe-api-highlights-datetimestring-handling-time-intervals-and-udafs.html

Comment: I've tried searching and using "NOW()" and "current_date" but I got following exceptions:

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: undefined function NOW;
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'current_date' given input columns ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution of my question in using `org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext` instead `org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext`. Now following code works as expected:

```
lazy val sc = ... // create Spak Context
lazy val hc = new HiveContext(sc)
val results = hc.sql("SELECT record_name as name FROM test_table WHERE day < current_date")
results.take(10)
  .map(r => s"name: ${r.getAs("name")}")
  .foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 2):

current_date() works for me on Spark 1.5

Example usage:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT current_date() as today FROM eventsAvro").first
```

Outputs:

```
res360: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [2016-01-29]
```